# I am using Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH, When I run the file I'm getting the following error:

Tags: android, android-intent

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int CALL = 1;

    private static String[] PERMISSION = {
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
    };

    public static void verifyThatWeCanCallSomeone(Activity activity) {
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //we don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSION,
                    CALL
            );
        }
    }

    Button btnOpenUdemy, btnSearchGoogle, btnCall, btnAccessDialPad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        verifyThatWeCanCallSomeone(MainActivity.this);

        btnOpenUdemy = findViewById(R.id.btnOpenUdemy);
        btnSearchGoogle = findViewById(R.id.btnSearchGoogle);
        btnCall = findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
        btnAccessDialPad = findViewById(R.id.btnAccessDialPad);

        btnOpenUdemy.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        btnSearchGoogle.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        btnCall.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        btnAccessDialPad.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnOpenUdemy:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.udemy.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.btnSearchGoogle:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                intent1.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;

            case R.id.btnCall:

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},CALL);
                    }
                    else{
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent3.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9920496151"));
            startActivity(intent3);
                    }
                break;

            case R.id.btnAccessDialPad:

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.app45, PID: 15917
                                                                                                    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH dat=http://www.google.com/... }
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2087)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1747)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5404)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5362)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5748)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5701)
                                                                                                        at com.example.app45.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:68)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28676)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

When I click on btnSearchGoogle button, I got error.

The line of code at line 68:

```
case R.id.btnSearchGoogle:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                intent1.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
```

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app45, PID: 15917
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH dat=http://www.google.com/... }

Can any one suggest a answer for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee to be an app on the device to handle every `Intent`. Wrap your `startActivity()` call in a `try`/`catch` and alert the user if you get an exception.

Beyond that, you did not follow [the instructions for using `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH). It does not take a `Uri`, and you did not provide a value for the `QUERY` string extra.